# Strong convexity and the Legendre transform

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, inner-products, transformation

Suppose that I have a strongly convex function $f(\mathbf{x}): \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is the Legendre transform of this function also strongly convex?

As far as I can tell, strict convexity of $f$ implies strict convexity of the Legendre transform of $f$ (as shown in https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Convexity_of_Function_implies_Convexity_of_its_Legendre_Transform). However, I am unsure as to whether the same argument holds for strongly convex $f$.

EDIT: The following link appears to support this claim for the case of $m =1$. https://books.google.ca/books?id=HjznBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=linear+programming+vanderbei+strongly+convex+legendre+transform&source=bl&ots=mBLOVV7_a0&sig=xMI0kBz7bHdN4kkEnvQQ87LGkhk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiayNCfupXVAhVFeSYKHQI_Dl8Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=linear%20programming%20vanderbei%20strongly%20convex%20legendre%20transform&f=false

Comment: Ah, too bad that proof you cited assumes differentiability. I was hoping for something more general! Interesting question.

Comment: **Thm:** $f$ is $\sigma$-strongly convex iff $f^*$ is $1/\sigma$-smooth. http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~shai/papers/KakadeShalevTewari09.pdf

Comment: @MichaelGrant - I am hoping that strong convexity is sufficient. Of course, if some smoothness is required, that's ok. However, I don't want a result in which smoothness itself is sufficient to guarantee strong convexity.

Comment: @dohmatob - So, this begs the question: does strong convexity guarantee 1/$\sigma$ smoothness?

Comment: That is what the "iff" means, yes

Comment: @MichaelGrant -No, I meant the following: is strong convexity of $f^*$ equivalent to $1/\sigma$ smoothness of $f^*$?

Comment: Oh, that's a different matter indeed, and I doubt it.

Comment: The elastic-net penalty $\|.\|_1 + \|.\|^2_2$ is strongly convex but nonsmooth, let alone strongly smooth.

Comment: @dohmatob - Perhaps the claim is not true in general (for any $m$). However, please see the edit to my post. Thanks for your help and your patience on this question.